# sqlite register is updated with wrong values on android app

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

In my current android project, the method for update a row in my sqlite database receive as parameter a array like this:

```
String form[] = {id, first_name, last_name, email, login, password};
user.update(form);
```

which is processed through this code:

```
  public void update(String[] data) {
    try {
      Model object = clazz.newInstance();
      List<String> campos = object.getFields();
      List<String> pares = new ArrayList<String>();

      for(int i=1; i<campos.size(); i++)
        pares.add(campos.get(i)+" = ?");

      String spares = pares.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", " and ");
      String UPDATE = "update " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " set " + spares + " where _id='" + data[0] + "'";

      SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      SQLiteStatement updateStmt = db.compileStatement(UPDATE);

      for(int i=1; i<data.length; i++)
        updateStmt.bindString(i, data[i]);

      updateStmt.executeUpdateDelete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

generating a sql instruction like that:

```
update Usuario set first_name = ? and  last_name = ? and  email = ? and  login = ? and  password = ? where _id='1'
```

the problem is only the first column is being updated, and with the value '0'. Anyone can se what's wrong here?

Comment: Simply remove the last replace instruction: `.replace(",", " and ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for an SQL UPDATE is like

```
update Usuario set first_name = ?, last_name = ? ...
```

i.e. commas intead of `AND`. The `AND` makes it a boolean expression that evaluates to 0 (false).